# Some file permissions have '??????????' under LxC - Is this a feature, or a sign of a corrupt file-system?

Tags: hard-drive, fsck, ubuntu-16.04, lxc, lvm2

I ran into the following listing quite by chance:

```
[root@myhost /root]# cd /var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/devices/

[root@myhost /var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/devices]# ls -l
ls: cannot access 'devices.allow': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'devices.deny': Permission denied
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 10:56 cgroup.clone_children
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 10:56 cgroup.procs
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 10:56 cgroup.sane_behavior
?????????? ? ?    ?    ?            ? devices.allow
?????????? ? ?    ?    ?            ? devices.deny
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 10:56 devices.list
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Nov  4 10:56 init.scope
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 10:56 notify_on_release
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 10:56 release_agent
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Nov  4 10:56 system.slice
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  4 10:56 tasks
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Nov  4 10:56 user.slice

[root@myhost /var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/devices]#
```

When I googled for the reason behind those question marks above, a link suggested that this may be a sign of my HDD failing, or a corrupt file-system.

And, there are 100's of such files (with `?`'s against their names) under my `.../lxcfs/` directory that I've not shown above.

So, I ran an `fsck.ext4` on my logical volume (where the above `/` filesystem resides) in the hope of finding some problems at least. But, to my surprise, I found none.

What is going on? Is this normal with LxC... LxC using some obscure Linux feature that I'm not aware of?

I'm using:

- LxC: 2.0.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.2
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please check with `mount` whether this is a virtual filesystem. It should be. As such, it does not rely on any drive.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I see this entry: `lxcfs on /var/lib/lxcfs type fuse.lxcfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)`. So, this, then, means everything's okay?!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been a bug with lxcfs, mentioned in [this message on the lxc-devel mailing list](https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-devel/2016-October/014866.html), where getting the file attributes was denied for write-only files like devices.allow.

It was reportedly fixed in later versions of lxcfs, based on [this Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxcfs/+bug/1656309).